# Is a brick with a smaller Lego logo real?

Tags: piece-information, manufacturing

I recently bought a set from Bricklink, and noticed while building that a couple of pieces had a slightly different logo placement and size. The larger logo matched all my other bricks, but the smaller one didn’t.

I’m wondering if this is a fake brick, or is a result of a different / older mould? I did some quick searching online and couldn’t find anything related to this issue, but the gloss and colour of each piece appears to be the same, and both include the same correct piece ID (although again printed slightly differently). I bought the set boxed but used, and everything seemed right so I’m assuming it’s genuine but just looking for some peace of mind, and curious as to what would lead to this difference.

Many thanks in advance!

[image: bottom view][image: top view]

Comment: Item with smaller LEGO logo is odd one indeed. Haven't seen anything like this before. And it is not just the size but the text is not as prominent as well.

Comment: "the text is not as prominent as well" but it is very high precision, which I think many counterfeits screw up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many sets have had mold changes over the years, as they get slightly redesigned, or even just wear out. I would rest at ease.

It's the old pieces that don't have ANY markings that say Lego that always worry me.

Edited: I took photos of two Duplo train track pieces I noticed today. I merged them together to show the scales are (very close to) the same, yet the logo sizes are quite different. I also included the untouched photos for completeness, and because they're easier to read.

In summary: Lego changes their logo size on the same part.
[image: composite image]
[image: smaller logo]
[image: larger logo]